# Proof and name of a polynomial division theorem in $\mathbb {Z}[x]$, $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

I am looking for the name and proof of the theorem that states If a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ then $\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is a [divided difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DividedDifference.html). Kahan gives a constructive proof of the more general fact that the divided difference of a polynomial as a function of $a$ and $b$ is a polynomial in $a$ and $b$, using more or less Kenny's observation.

Answer (score 1):

It's an immediate consequence of the Remainder Theorem, which says there is a polynomial $q(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $$f(x)=(x-b)q(x)+f(b)$$ Evaluate at $x=a$ to get $f(a)=(a-b)q(a)+f(b)$, which says $${f(a)-f(b)\over a-b}=q(a)$$ is an integer, since $q$ has integer coefficients and $a$ is an integer.